# 5GHz WiFI speed much slower than on 2.4GHz on my Macbook air 2017

Tags: macbook-pro, wifi, performance, big-sur, router

I just setup my new Xiaomi WiFi MiRouter 4A gigabit edition router but my Macbook has only 3MBs speed of uploading while on 2.4GHz speed is 60MBs. Also on iphone and other devices is almost 200Mbs speed. I deleted my antivirus app and vpn but still didn't help. I don't know what to do.

Comment: What is the distance to the router, what is in between? 5 GHz will suffer much more when walls are in the way.

Comment: it doesn't matter, i was standing close to router and speed was still slow. Noticed one more issue that only windows notebook and iphone X has high speed, other devices(Macbook, iphone 6/6s) has low speed

Answer (score -1):

Found solution. Issue was in the settings of bandwidth, changed from 20Mhz to 80 Mhz.

Comment: Please give more detail. Would this happen in a different router?

Comment: I dont know about other routers but Xiaomi router sets channel and bandwidth to Auto which doesnt work properly, to fix it i changed manually in settings bandwidth to 80 Mhz and channel to any free one